# What is the variance of X?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, variance

Consider an urn with four balls: one ball is worth 3, two balls are worth 8 each, and one ball is worth 11.  Suppose you randomly draw two balls from the urn at the same time. Let random variable $X$ denote the sum of the values of these two balls.  What is the variance of $X$?

I made a value set for the sum of balls drawn, $X= \{11,14,16,19\}$
I made a sample space for possible combinations of balls drawn $S= \{(3,8)(8,3)(3,11)(11,3)(8,8)(11,8)(8,11)\}$

Probability of scoring 11 = probability of selecting $(3,8)$ or $(8,3)$: $P(X=11) = 2/7$

Probability of scoring 14 = probability of selecting $(3,11)$ or $(11,3)$: $P(X=14) = 2/7$

Probability of scoring 16 = probability of selecting $(8,8)$: $P(X=16) = 1/7$

Probability of scoring 19 = probability of selecting $(11,8)$ or $(8,11)$: $P(X=19) = 2/7$

$E(X) = (2/7 \cdot 11 + 2/7 \cdot 14 + 1/7 \cdot 16 + 2/7 \cdot 19 ) = 14.857$

Required to find Variance 
\begin{align*}
V(X) &= (2/7 * (11^2) + 2/7 * (14^2) + 1/7 * (16^2) + 2/7 * (19^2) ) - (E(X))^2 \\
                               & = 230.286 - 220.730 \\
                               & = 9.556
\end{align*}

Is this approach and my answer correct?

Comment: You approach is basically correct except for the sample space. Since we do not consider the order of balls drawn from this urn, there are only four possible outcomes: $\{(3,8),(3,11),(8,8),(8,11)\}$. The remaining are essential the same as what did above.

Comment: @BernardPan Try simulating this: the probability of getting $19$ should be higher than getting $14$ as there are more $8$-balls then $3$-balls

Comment: @Henry I did not say that they are equally likely.

Comment: @BernardPan - though you did say the remaining are essentially the same as what lothric123 did above.

Comment: @Henry My bad. I should have said that the formulae of calculating the expectation and variance are the same.

Answer (score 1):

To use a counting argument, you need to check that all draws are equally likely.  Since you are choosing two from four possible balls without replacement, there should be ${4 \choose 2}=6$ equally likely possibilities (or $4\times 3=12$ if order matters).

These $6$ are

$$\{3,8_a\}, \{3,8_b\}, \{3,11\}, \{8_a,8_b\}, \{8_a,11\}, \{8_b,11\}$$

while the $12$ are

$$(3,8_a), (3,8_b), (3,11), (8_a,3), (8_a,8_b), (8_a,11), \\(8_b,3), (8_b,8_a), (8_b,11), (11,3), (11, 8_a), (11, 8_b)$$

Either will do: you can now add up the pairs and count the sums, and get the probabilities of $\frac13,\frac16,\frac16,\frac13$